# How to restrict access to fields based on access level in graphql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, graphql

I have a table with 10 columns. How to limit access to certain users to 3 or 4 of the column values alone(based on the access level).

Also how can i still return data for other columns and add error message only for those restricted columns/fields?

Comment: Checkout Policy Scopes in Pundit: https://github.com/varvet/pundit#scopes

Answer (score 0):

You can use resolver for this fields:

```
fieldName: {
  type: GraphQLString,
  resolve (data, a, b, { rootValue: _ }) {
    if(!_.user.isAdmin) throw new Error('restricted')
    return data.fieldName;
}
```